# behaviour of unix process when a signal arrives and the process is already in signal handler?

Tags: unix, signals

I have a process which is already in signal handler , and called a process blocking call. What will happen if one more signal arrives for this process ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default signals don't block each other. A signal only blocks itself during its own delivery. So, in general, an handling code can be interrupted by another signal delivery.
You can control this behavior by setting the process signal mask relatively to each signal delivery. This means that you can block (or serialize) signal delivery. For instance you can declare that you accept to be interrupted with signal S1 while handling signal S2, but not the converse...
Remember that signal delivery introduces some concurrency into your code, so controlling the blocking is needed.

Comment: what exactly my code do is - It has a signal handler for SIGUSR1. In the handler for SIGUSR1, I make a call to a blocking system call. So now the entire process is blocked while executing the signal handler. At this time , if again a SIGUSR1 signal is sent to the process ..what is the behavior?

Comment: The second SIGUSR1 is blocked until you get off the handler. While you are in the delivery of the first SIGUSR1 instance, SIGUSR1 is blocked (it is pending).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure signals are blocked while a handler is being executed, but I'm having a hard time finding something that says that definitively.

Also, you may wish to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707254/non-reentrant-function-in-signal-handler) - some of the answers talk about what functions you should and shouldn't call from a signal handler.

In general, you should consider a signal handler like an interrupt handler - do the very least you can in the handler, and return quickly.